# Are there any wildcards to exclude by name in the search field?

Tags: interface

For example, I have Leg.R and Leg.CTRL.R bones. I want to set such a search so that it removes the word "CTRL". But the invert button won't help here because I want it to be in common search bar.
For example, I want to find only the hands or fingers of the right hand, but without the word "CTRL", and the invert button will not help here.

Comment: what object type do you want to search by name? Could you up load a image to let us more easy to understand

Comment: @XY The example he gives in the question says it's bones. I think it's quite easy to understand. Let's say his model has an armature with lots of bones. The ones on the right have a suffix '.R' and the ones on the left have '.L' and some seem to be controller bones which also have a secondary suffix '.CTRL' before the '.R' and '.L'. Now if the right hand has bone names like 'hand.finger1.R', 'hand.finger1.CTRL.R' 'hand.finger2.R', 'hand.finger2.CTRL.R' etc. he wants to filter for something like 'finger*.R', but he doesn't want those bones which have a '.CTRL' inbetween.

Comment: Gordon Brinkmann, yes, that's exactly what I mean! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to select them or rename them?

**1)** Make sure you are in **Object mode** and **select** the armature object.
**2)** Go to **Text Editor** paste the text:

```
import bpy

oj = bpy.context.object
bones = oj.data.bones

for bo in bones:
    bo.select = True  if bo.name.find("CTRL") == -1 else False
```

**3) Run** the script, the bone will select if name not include "CTRL"

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Blender has a [batch rename](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/rename.html#find-replac) function that takes wildcard format called regular expressions. [Regular expressions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) can be very flexible and have form that says must have this part but not that. you just have to find the right wildcard for your search.

Comment: That's the thing, it doesn't exist. I tested different characters before posting this question. I know for sure that ?, * and [] work.
For example, in the link you gave, they write:
"[^b]at matches all strings matched by .at except "bat"."
Ok. But it doesn't work in Blender.

Comment: Can the built-in Batch Rename feature grab let's say Object Name and use that as a prefix for Object Data such as Mesh Name?